# Algorithm to identify if tree is subtree of other tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am reading cracking the coding interview, and I have a question on the solution of the following problem:
You have two very large binary trees: T1, with millions of nodes, and T2, with hundreds of nodes. Create an algorithm to decide if T2 is a subtree of T1.

The simple solution that it suggests is to create a string representing the in-order and pre-order traversals and check if T2s pre-order/in-order traversal is substring of T1's pre-order/in-order traversal.

What I wonder is why do we need to compare both traversals? And why exactly that two traversals, why not for example in-order and post-order. And mainly won't only one traversal be enough? Say only in-order or pre-order traversal?

Comment: First let's clarify what you mean by "subtree".  The standard graph-theoretical meaning would be "a subgraph formed by deleting zero or more vertices and edges from a tree, and which is itself a tree" -- but there is another commonly used meaning, namely "delete an edge; 2 connected components remain, both of which are subtrees".  The former definition includes some trees that the latter doesn't.

Comment: Interestingly, the algorithm you gave won't work for some reasonable definitions of "subtrees": as a mathematician, I would call 2<-1->3 a subtree of 4<-2<-1->3->5.  But the preorder of the first is not a substring of the second.

Comment: When you say "Binary Tree", can we assume that they are "Binary Search Tree" (ie, a parent is less than any of its two children)? Also, are the values on the nodes unique in each tree, or not?

Answer (score 3):

One traversal isn't enough.  Consider the graphs 1->2->3 and 2<-1->3.  If you start with node 1 and do a traversal, you encounter the nodes in the order 1, 2, 3.  If you simply create a string showing the pre-order the two give the same result: `1,2,3`

On the other hand, if you use a post-order, then the two will give a different result. `3,2,1` and `2,3,1`

I bet for any one ordering, you can find two different trees with the same result.

So the question you need to answer for yourself for any other pair you want to look at is: would there be a tree that would give the same order for both traversals?  I'm going to leave that as something to think about and come back later to see if you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think preorder traversal with sentinel to represent null node is enough.
we can use this approach to serialize/deserialize a binary tree. That means, it is an one-to-one mapping between a binary tree to its preorder+sentinel representation.

After we get strings for both small tree and big tree. then we do a string match using kmp algorithm.

I know people are saying that we have to use both preorder and inorder (or postorder and inorder). but most of them just follow what others are saying, rather than think independently.